# acquiring tablecell row index

Tags: javafx, tablecell, tablecolumn

A simplified view of the problem I'm having....

- A TableView TV contains two TableColumns (Name, Value).
- A data structure Class obj_data contains two data items, SimpleStringProperty location, and double X. Multiple obj_data objects are stored in an observalable list and used with the TableView TV as it's data source
- In the rendering of TableColumn Name, I need to get and the interrogate the value the corresponding X in order to change some visual attribute of the location tableCell..

I've played around with...

nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback, ObservableValue>()...

to return the value of obj_data element but am having difficulty trying to get the index of the table cell so I can correctly render the "location" field.. Hope this makes sense!

PS: This was so much more simple pre-javaFX with cellrenderers since I could get the row & col locations in the callback arguments!
Thanks in advance!